# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' when sending GET request

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, date-formatting, get-request

I have this method in my Controller (This is a Kotlin method, but I think you can understand it):

```
open fun getAis(
        @RequestParam("beginPeriodDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") beginPeriodDate: Date,
        @RequestParam("request") request: Boolean,
        @RequestParam("requestNumber") requestNumber: String,
        @RequestParam("sender") sender: String
): Data =
        service.get(beginPeriodDate, request, requestNumber, sender)
```

And I am trying to reach it via browser. I'm sending this: `http://localhost:8097/shep/sync/ais?beginPeriodDate=2019-08-25?request=false?requestNumber=272710100307142417?sender=2727851024302531`

And getting this:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 
'java.util.Date'; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to 
 convert from type [java.lang.String] to type 
[@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam 
@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for 
value '2019-08-25?request=false?requestNumber='2710100307142417'? 
sender='27851024302531''; nested exception is 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2019-08-25? 
request=false?requestNumber='27..." is malformed at "?request=false? 
requestNumber='27..."
```

Comment: Replace all `?` with `&` leave only the first `?`. Basically the URL you are using for testing is wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, it works, thanks. Why is it wrong? Because of `/shep/sync/ais` part?

Comment: The `?` indicates in the URL the start of the parameters. The `&` is used to separate parameters.

Comment: Yup @M.Deinum is right your URL must look like that `http://localhost:8097/shep/sync/ais?beginPeriodDate=2019-08-25&request=false&requestNumber=272710100307142417&sender=2727851024302531`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your request URI is malformed 
& delimits parameters, not ?. in other words what you need is

```
?beginPeriodDate=2019-08-25&request=false&requestNumber='2710100307142417'&sender='27851024302531'
```

also, if there's no particular reason to do it, i would drop the single quotes around requestNumber and sender values, which would make it look like this

```
?beginPeriodDate=2019-08-25&request=false&requestNumber=2710100307142417&sender=27851024302531
```